# Jquery Control image move up and down inside div

Tags: jquery, css, animation

**Jquery Control image move up and down inside div**
Hi, i need your help by make image move up and down inside some div ,

for example ( i saw the example in stackoverflow)

http://jsfiddle.net/PKBXL/29/

Comment: so, create your own fiddle based on the sample provided

Comment: Seems to be working fine by me...Please explain how you want the bee to move.

Comment: Up and down , when its come to the bottom of the "wrapper" it will go up and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var intId = setInterval(animateImage,1000);
    var intId=   setInterval(animateupImage,1000);
}); 

function animateImage() {
    $('#bee').animate({bottom: '-50%'}, 3000, 'linear', 1000);
      }
function animateupImage() {
   $('#bee').animate({bottom: '0%'}, 3000, 'linear',1000 );
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/PKBXL/42/)